# Swift use of undeclared type FetchedResultController

Tags: swift2

I'm new to Swift and am trying to populate a table from Core Data. I get a "use of undeclared type 'Rooms'" in the following code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class RoomTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    /
    let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    /
    var frc : NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /
        frc = getFRC()

        frc.delegate = self

        /
        fetch(frc)

        /
        /
        /
        /
    }
    /
    func fetch(frcToFetch: NSFetchedResultsController) {

        do {
            try frcToFetch.performFetch()
        } catch {
            let fetchError = error as NSError
            print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    func getFRC() -> NSFetchedResultsController {

        frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        return frc
    }

    func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Rooms")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "roomName", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        return fetchRequest
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        /
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    /
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        /
        let numberOfSections = frc.sections?.count
        return numberOfSections!


    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        /
        /
        let numberOfRowsInSection = frc.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
        return numberOfRowsInSection!    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let room = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Rooms

        print(room)

        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(room.roomName!)"
        return cell
    }

    /
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        /
        return true
    }

    /
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            /
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            /
        }  
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: do you have a class called `Rooms`?

Comment: My Entity is called Rooms. I created a subclass using the Create NSManagedObject Subclass command, but the command appended my app name to the subclass name.